# java8 grouping by custom value custom map value

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

java8

```
public class CustomDate{    
    LocalDateTime datetime;   
}

List<CustomDate>  list = // 2 dates with multiple times
```

I want to group dates by day and values as times following gives me CustomDate as values?

```
Map<LocalDate, List<CustomDate>> map = 
         list.stream().groupingBy(d-> d.datetime.toLocalDate())
```

any help is appreciated.

Comment: what? this is unclear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class Dates {

    private static List< CustomDate > list = new ArrayList<>(  );

    public static void main( String[] args ) {

        Map< LocalDate, List< LocalTime > > result2 = list.stream()
            .map( CustomDate::getDatetime )
            .collect(
                HashMap::new,
                Dates::accept,
                Dates::merge
            );

    }

    private static void accept( HashMap< LocalDate, List< LocalTime > > map, LocalDateTime date ) {

        map.putIfAbsent( date.toLocalDate( ), new ArrayList<>())
           .add( date.toLocalTime( ) );
    }

    private static void merge( Map< LocalDate, List< LocalTime > > map1, Map< LocalDate, List< LocalTime > > map2 ) {

        map2.forEach( (date,timeList) -> {
            map1.merge( date, timeList, ( l1, l2 ) -> {
                l1.addAll( l2 );
                return l1;
            } );
        });

    }
}
```

Or simply:

```
Map< LocalDate, List< LocalTime > > result2 = list.stream()
    .map( CustomDate::getDatetime )
    .collect(
        HashMap::new,
        (map,date) -> {
             map.putIfAbsent( date.toLocalDate( ), new ArrayList<>(   )).add( date.toLocalTime( ) );
        },
        (map1, map2) -> {
            map2.forEach( (date,timeList) -> {
                map1.merge( date, timeList, ( l1, l2 ) -> {
                    l1.addAll( l2 );
                    return l1;
                } );
            }); 
        }
    );
```

Doing it not so declaratively as calling 3 times the collectors static methods, gives you much more control to dictate behavior, like using a initial size for your arrays, using specific lists and so on, without losing the sugar coming from the declarative style.

```
Map< LocalDate, List< LocalTime > > result2 = list.stream()
    .map( CustomDate::getDatetime )
    .collect(
        TreeMap::new,
        (map,date) -> {
             map.putIfAbsent( date.toLocalDate( ), new ArrayList<>( 800  )).add( date.toLocalTime( ) );
        },
        (map1, map2) -> {
            map2.forEach( (date,timeList) -> {
                map1.merge( date, timeList, ( l1, l2 ) -> {
                    l1.addAll( l2 );
                    return l1;
                } );
            }); 
        }
    );
```

Of course if the default behavior is acceptable, this is way simpler:

```
    Map<LocalDate, List<LocalTime>> result = list.stream()
            .map( CustomDate::getDatetime )
            .collect(groupingBy(LocalDateTime::toLocalDate,
                     mapping(LocalDateTime::toLocalTime,toList())));
```

Another way to go is to define your own collector, which is what I usually prefer. By doing that you gain both, control and the ability to code your logic declaratively, and reuse when needed.

Which would reduce you code to:

```
Map< LocalDate, List< LocalTime > > result2 = list.stream()
            .collect(
                    customDateCollector()
            );
```

If you had something like:

```
class CustomDateCollector implements Collector<CustomDate, Map< LocalDate, List< LocalTime > >, Map< LocalDate, List< LocalTime > >> {

    @Override
    public Supplier< Map< LocalDate, List< LocalTime > > > supplier( ) {

        return HashMap::new;
    }

    @Override
    public BiConsumer< Map< LocalDate, List< LocalTime > >, CustomDate > accumulator( ) {
        int goodStartUsingProblemKnowledge = 30;
        return (map, customDate) -> map.putIfAbsent( customDate.getDatetime().toLocalDate(), new ArrayList<>( goodStartUsingProblemKnowledge) )
                                       .add(  customDate.getDatetime().toLocalTime() );
    }

    @Override
    public BinaryOperator< Map< LocalDate, List< LocalTime > > > combiner( ) {

        return (map1, map2) -> {
                map2.forEach( (date,timeList) -> {
                    map1.merge( date, timeList, ( list1, list2 ) -> {
                        list1.addAll( list2 );
                        return list1;
                    } );
                });
                return map1;
        };
    }

    @Override
    public Function< Map< LocalDate, List< LocalTime > >, Map< LocalDate, List< LocalTime > > > finisher( ) {

        return Function.identity();
    }

    @Override
    public Set< Characteristics > characteristics( ) {

        return Collections.unmodifiableSet( EnumSet.of( IDENTITY_FINISH, UNORDERED,CONCURRENT) );
    }

    public static CustomDateCollector customDateCollector(){
        return new CustomDateCollector();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

It seems like you want to group by the date and have the map values as `LocalTime` instead of `CustomDate`.

```
Map<LocalDate, List<LocalTime>> result = list.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(e -> e.getDatetime().toLocalDate(),
                        Collectors.mapping(e -> e.getDatetime().toLocalTime(),
                                Collectors.toList())));
```

Comment: thanks, Eugene i thought my question was simple not sure why mind reading skil need :D

Comment: @d-man it's probably clear to you, but I've read it 5 times now still did not understand it. How about this is the List I have and I want output to be `Map<LocalDate, List<LocalTime>>`... this would have made a lot more sense

Comment: @Eugene I thought you'd ask the secret behind this "_mind reading_" skill by now? ;)

Comment: Why not do a single `getDatetime()` before the `collect`?→`list.stream() .map(CustomDate::getDatetime).collect(Collectors.groupingBy(LocalDateTime ::toLocalDate, Collectors.mapping(LocalDateTime::toLocalTime, Collectors.toList())));`

Comment: @Holger good call that's better, although the call to `getDatetime()` is very lightweight and one shouldn't be too worried about.

Answer (score 0):

As in answer from **Aominè** you should use `Collectors.groupingBy()`. But I reccomend you to do some additional steps.

**1** Create `GroupUtils` class with some general code teamplates:

```
public final class GroupUtils {

    public static <K, V> Map<K, List<V>> groupMultipleBy(Collection<V> data, Function<V, K> classifier) {
        return groupMultipleBy(data, classifier, Function.identity());
    }

    public static <K, V, S> Map<K, List<S>> groupMultipleBy(Collection<V> data, Function<V, K> classifier, Function<V, S> mapper) {
        return Optional.ofNullable(data).orElse(Collections.emptyList()).stream()
                       .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(classifier, Collectors.mapping(mapper, Collectors.toList())));
    }
}
```

This is example from one of my project. Here I have more similar methods.

**2** In local file, do create concrete method, to make client's code much more readable.

```
class Client {

    public static void main(String... args) {
        List<CustomDate> list = Collections.emptyList();
        Map<LocalDateTime, List<CustomDate>> map = groupByDatetime(list);
    }

    private static Map<LocalDateTime, List<CustomDate>> groupByDatetime(List<CustomDate> list) {
        return GroupUtils.groupMultipleBy(list, CustomDate::getDatetime);        
    }
}
```

I believe this is a little bit more code, but much more readable than:

```
Map<LocalDate, List<LocalTime>> result = list.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(e -> e.getDatetime().toLocalDate(),
                        Collectors.mapping(e -> e.getDatetime().toLocalTime(),
                                Collectors.toList())));
```

Comment: it's `Collectors.groupingBy` not `Collectors.groupBy`

Comment: and also *in your opinion* is this more readable, I find your solution a lot less readable, but it might be just me

Comment: well I also don't like the `Optional.ofNullable` either; if you talk about being readable if could be done as `public static <K, V, S> Map<K, List<S>> groupMultipleBy(Collection<V> data, Function<V, K> classifier, Function<V, S> mapper) {
        if (data == null) {
            return Collections.emptyMap();
        }
        return data.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                        classifier,
                        Collectors.mapping(mapper, Collectors.toList())));
    }`

Comment: @Eugene if you think that `groupByDatetime(list)` is less readable than full `Collection.groupBy()`, then I don't have more arguments.

Comment: that is the point, it's something that you (and your colleagues probably) use a lot - so you are aware if it; I don't - thus don't really trust it, thus would have to understand the implementation to actually "get it", while the other solution *is* straightforward. It all depends how you look at it

Comment: wait - did you just try to silence the internet here for a moment, hahahahaha u made my day!

Comment: Is there any reason to include that special `null` handling that no-one asked for?